# ajaxStop() doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code that wasn't working:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $(this).unbind("ajaxStop"); //prevent running again when other calls finish

    // Display everything
    display();
});
```

And here's my Ajax function:

```
function getAjax(url, callback) {
    jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function( options ) {
        options.global = true;
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: callback
    });
}
```

Why does `ajaxStop()` never fire?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll notice I was making JSONP requests. It took me forever to find this, but the answer to this issue can be found [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8338#comment:1).

From the ticket:

> JSONP requests are not guaranteed to complete (because errors are not
> caught). jQuery 1.5 forces the global option to false in that case so
> that the internal ajax request counter is guaranteed to get back to
> zero at one point or another.
>
> If you want all requests to fire the events, no matter what (and at the risk of the same inconsistencies 1.4.4 exhibited), you can use the following prefilter:

```
jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function( options ) {
    options.global = true;
});
```

> Case in point:  http://jsfiddle.net/X4JTx/