# Catching net::ERR_ABORTED in Ajax JsonP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am making an ajax call as follows.  Everything works fine when a valid status or data is returned.
I am attempting to reset some state values after any return but in this case none of the events are executing after a `net::ERR_ABORTED` is received, therefore I cannot reset the state.  For what it's worth, this is calling a .Net REST endpoint.

```
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        contentType: "application/javascript",
        url: "http://...",
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError) 
        { 
            console.log('error: ' + textStatus);
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) 
        { 
            console.log('success: ' + textStatus);
        },
        complete: function (xhr, textStatus) 
        { 
            console.log('complete: ' + textStatus);
        }
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log('done');
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, exception) {
        console.log('fail');
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log('always');
    });
```

I did try to set [ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226776/ajaxstop-doesnt-fire) but it still did not fire.  How can I capture this `ERR_ABORTED` or execute code regardless of the return?

Comment: **If it's cross-domain, you can't.** also, `contentType: "application/javascript",` isn't necessary. you aren't sending data, and even if you were you can't set the contentType of the data you are sending through a JSONP request.

Comment: The best you can do is a timeout

Comment: Thanks for the advice regarding contentType.  I didn't think that one through and it makes sense.  Regarding the other... Damn.